# how to implement form button in jade files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

Hello so i am new to jade and i wanna know how would i add a button to my form within a jade file, this is my jade file so far

```
extends layout

block content
    form(name="getomdb",method='get')
        div.input
            span.label Title
            input(type="text",name="movie")

        div.container
            h3#title
                p#plot
```

I have tried googling around and searching for the same question on stack overflow but i get no success. Is there a guide to learning jade anywhere im just trying to figure it out using an omdbapi so i can pull tomato ratings and such from it

Comment: look at the pug (formerly jade) syntax...it's very intuitive, do you know html?

Answer (score 3):

```
extends layout

block content
form(name="getomdb",method='get')
    div.input
        span.label Title
        input(type="text",name="movie")
    input(type="submit", value="Submit")

    div.container
        h3#title
            p#plot
```